# Can't see NAS with introduction of BT Home Hub

Tags: nas, home-hub

I've been running a home network based around a Linksys router for years. We had a couple of PCs and a QNAP NAS wired to the hub and then numerous wifi-connected clients.

We've recently swapped the Linksys for a BT Home Hub. Now, client machines can only connect to the NAS via wifi; wired connections do not work. This is true for all machines and I have test wired and wireless on all those capable.

Any help / suggestions much appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

OK, as per usual, I figure out the answer within minutes of asking the question!

The problem was that the new router will issue IP addresses below 192.168.1.100 to wired clients. The NAS was configured to only allow a range starting at 100.

Changed the security setting on the NAS, problem solved!